# How do I achive total percentage by SubCategory and distribution range considering YearMonth filter in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I am trying to get the total percentage using DAX measure but end up getting percentage breakdown by range and subcategory only, it won't show 100% distribution along with subcategory and ranges.

I have data in tabular cube like this with total by subcategory based on customers,

```
YearMonth   PercentRange    SubCategory     TotalCount
202005      1%-19.99%       Sub1            280
202005      1%-19.99%       Sub2            280
202005      20%-39.99%      Sub1            52
202005      20%-39.99%      Sub2            270
```

Expected results,

```
YearMonth   PercentRange    Sub1    Measure Sub2 Measure
202005      20%-39.99%      280     84%     280  60%
202005      1%-19.99%       52      16%     270  40%
Grand Total                 320     100%    550  100%
```

DAX i have tried,
This DAX gives result if I use only 202005 but doesn't work if I include another month :(

```
IF (
    ISFILTERED (TableA[PercentRange]),
    [Head Count]
    /
    CALCULATE (
             [Head Count],
            ALL( TableA[PercentRange]) -- I could use some logic here to get subtotal for Subcategory
    )
)
```

Thanks for the helps!!

Answer (score 0):

are you still stuck? You should try using SELECTEDVALUE with FILTER, like this:

```
SubCateg% = [SumTotalCount] / CALCULATE([SumTotalCount];
FILTER(ALL(TableA);
TableA[SubCategory]=SELECTEDVALUE(TableA[SubCategory])))
```

That way it will always count the % by subcategories.

Answer (score 0):

Lets do everything in one go using a custom table and GROUP BY. Create "New table" with below code by click on the button shown in the below image-

[image]

Now just paste this following code in the script section-

> Considered your base table name = **percentage_subcategory**.
> Please change the table name reference accordingly.

```
group_by_sub_category = 
VAR sub_category_wise_total = 
GROUPBY (  
    percentage_subcategory,
    percentage_subcategory[YearMonth],
    percentage_subcategory[PercentRange],
    "sum_sub1",
        SUMX(
            CURRENTGROUP()
            , 
            IF(
                percentage_subcategory[SubCategory] = "Sub1",
                percentage_subcategory[TotalCount],
                BLANK()
            )
        )
    ,
    "sum_sub2",
        SUMX(
            CURRENTGROUP()
            , 
            IF(
                percentage_subcategory[SubCategory] = "Sub2",
                percentage_subcategory[TotalCount],
                BLANK()
            )
        )
    ,
    "sum_total_count", SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(), percentage_subcategory[TotalCount])
) 

RETURN
SELECTCOLUMNS (
    sub_category_wise_total,
    "YearMonth",percentage_subcategory[YearMonth],
    "PercentRange",percentage_subcategory[PercentRange],
    "sum_sub1",[sum_sub1],
    "sum_sub2",[sum_sub2],
    "sum_total_count", [sum_total_count],
    "sub1_percentage",([sum_sub1]/[sum_total_count]),
    "sub2_percentage",([sum_sub2]/[sum_total_count]) 
)
```

Now you have a new table in the report source with name "group_by_sub_category". Just change the data type of column "sub1_percentage" & "sub2_percentage" to Percentage by selecting both columns and click on the **%** sign in the top menu as shown in the below image-

[image]